# HTML META REDIRECT to old URL

Tags: caching, redirect, meta, http-redirect

I just wanted to redirect from e.g. www.example.com/example to another URL.
I tested it with this index.html in example.com/example and it looked like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://sample.org/sample">
</head>
Goto to URL <a href="http://sample.org/">http://sample.org/sample</a>
manually.
</html>
```

It worked just fine. Then I changed the "http://sample.org/sample" URL to the URL I wanted to redirect to.
But there occures the problem. It still redirects the example.com/example to sample.org/sample and not the actual one.

I tried to clear the cash, history and cookies in Firefox and did a DNS-Flush with "ipconfig /flushdns". 
I also deleted the folder example and created it new. But nothing helps.

When I'm accessing example.com/example/index.html it redirects to the URL I want to. But if I'm accessing example.com/example it still redirects to the unwanted sample.org/sample.

Any glues how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that the proxy in our company also does have a cache. I tested it outside of our company network and it worked just fine. So this is fixed ;)